# C# copying instance and modify new, while the previous is unchanged

Tags: c#, oop, object, instance

I have such a problem with creating a new instances of object based on the existing instances.

To explain better what I want to do - imagine
I have one instance which I am passing to function and I want to copy the content of this existing instance to another instance and add something more to this new instance (but what is important that the first instance is not going to be changed at all).

So the first instance is 'freezed' and the new one is cloned and modified.

What I have done is the model:

```
public class Scenario
{
    public List<SingleMove> listOfMoves { get; set; }
    public List<int> listOfScores { get; set; }
    public int totalScore { get; set; }

    public Scenario(Scenario currentScenario)
    {
        listOfMoves = currentScenario.listOfMoves;
        listOfScores = currentScenario.listOfScores;
        totalScore = currentScenario.totalScore;
    }
...
```

and now the function which is working on such objects

```
    static public void ActivitiesForMoveWhites(Scenario currentScenario, int positionTo, int positionFrom)
    {
        Scenario singleScenario = new Scenario(currentScenario);

        SingleMove singleMove = new SingleMove();
        singleMove.checker = Configuration.chessfield[positionFrom];
        singleMove.positionFrom = Logic.TranslateNumberOfFieldToString(positionFrom); //tutaj moze przechowywac to jako position czyli w intcie ?
        singleMove.positionTo = Logic.TranslateNumberOfFieldToString(positionTo); //tutaj moze przechowywac to jako position czyli w intcie ?
        singleScenario.listOfMoves.Add(singleMove);

        Configuration.listOfScenarios.Add(singleScenario);
        //Configuration.listOfScenarios.Add(new Scenario(singleScenario));
...
```

The problem is that all the different scenarios have the same listOfMoves. But it should be not like this. The current scenario should have copy the previous scenario content, add something, and the scenario that the content was copied from should stay at it was. So finally I have scenarios with different listOfMoves, not same !

Sorry for bit chaotic explanation. Please ask if you have questions or you need more details.

EDIT: 
There was one more question but I solved it.

Comment: `this.listOfMoves = that.listOfMoves` does not copy the list, it copies the reference to the same list. Add `.ToList()` to create a copy of the list.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thats not totally true. that works only when you have a non reference type for your list like `int`. If you have a reference type like a class instance then this won't copy the whole list. Specially to this case `listOfMoves.ToList()` won't work, but `listOfScores.ToList()` will work

Comment: @Jens yeah, obviously. We're talking about `List<T>` here though.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah, exactly. Just wanted to make that clear for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You must also clone the lists in your Scenario because = doesn't create a new instance of the list.
Try something like this in your constructor:

```
listOfMoves  = new List<SingleMove>(currentScenario.listOfMoves.Select(x => (SingleMove)x.Clone()));
```

Edit:

You must implement IClonable in your SingleMove Object

Comment: .. and cast the result of Clone() to SingleMove?